# I want that the value which was selected in first dropdown will not come in the second dropdown list value

Tags: angular

i have two dropdown, both dropdown binds different model. I want that the value which was selected in first dropdown will not come in the second dropdown list value.
 
                    Select Credit Ledger

Select Ledger

i just want when i select debit ledger, the value which is selected in credit ledger is not shown in debit ledger dropdown

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please add your code to your question, without hard to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering options with some code

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="creditLedger">
    <option *ngFor="let c of allOptions" [value]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="creditLedger">
    <option *ngFor="let c of filteredOptions" [value]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

.TS file:

```
public get allOptions(): Array<T> {
    return this.options;
}

public get filteredOptions(): Array<T> {
  return this.array.filter(v =>
    return v !== this.creditLedger;);
}
```

or

```
public get filteredOptions(): Array<T> {
     return this.options.splice(this.options.indexOf(this.creditLedger));
}
```

Comment: use "flat arrow" sintax, return this.array.filter(value=>value!=this.creditLedger)

Answer (score 0):

both selects are bind to one object. use two objects and you will be ok.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="creditLedger">
<option *ngFor="let c of options" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="ledger">
<option *ngFor="let c of options" [ngValue]="c">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

now value of selected options will be bind to creditLedger and ledger variables.